Show that the linear functional is unbounded in $C_{00}$. defined as $T$ is defined as $T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}},$
Given a linear functional $T: C_{00}\to C_{00}$. Where $C_{00}$ is space sequences with finitely many non-zero terms with $\ell_2$ norm.
$T$ is defined as $$T(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}},$$
Show that this functional is unbounded.
Initially Idea was to choose $x_n=\{1\}_{1\leq k\leq n}\in C_{00}$
This gives $$T(x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},$$
This gives $T(x_n)$ diverges hence functional is bounded.
Is this a correct approach.

Is the codomain $c_{00}$?

Yes it is mentioned there.

But $Tx$ is a number, isn't it?

More generally let $\{a_k\}\notin \ell^2.$ Then the linear functional defined on $C_{0,0}$ by
$$Tx=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kx_k$$ is unbounded. Indeed let $$x_k=\begin{cases}\overline{a_k} & 1\le k\le n\\ 0&k>n\end{cases}$$ Then $$\|x\|_2=\left (\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2\right)^{1/2},\quad Tx=\sum_{k=1}^n|a_k|^2$$ and $${Tx\over \|x\|_2}=\left (\sum_{k=1}^n |a_k|^2\right)^{1/2}\underset{n\to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$$
In the OP case $a_k=k^{-1/2}.$

Presumably $\ell_2$ is $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. Define the sequence $\mathbf{x}_m$ by
$$\mathbf{x}_m(n)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(m+1)}}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\mathbb{1}_{\{1,\ldots,m\}}(n)$$
Clearly $\mathbf{x}_n\in\mathcal{c}_{00}$ and
$\|\mathbf{x}_m\|^2_2=\frac{1}{\log(m+1)}\sum^m_{n=1}\frac1n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$.
This shows that $(\mathbf{x}_m:m\in\mathbb{N})$ is bounded in $\ell_2$. However,
$$T\mathbf{x}_m=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(m+1)}}\sum^m_{n=1}\frac1{n}\sim\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(m+1)}}\log(m)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$$
Consequently, $T$ is not a bounded functional.

For linear functionals the notion of boundedness rather corresponds to whether $|T(x)| \le C |x|$. In order to prove that your functionnal is unbounded, you must find a sequence $(x_n)$ of vectors such that $|T(x_n)| / |x_n| \rightarrow \infty$.
Therefore, the argument you gave is insufficient to prove unboundedness :
$$T(x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \sim \int_0^n  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}} \sim \sqrt n.$$
Moreover $|x_n| = \sqrt n$ so $|T(x_n)| / |x_n| \sim 1 $ does not diverge.
See the answer of @Mittens for a sequence $x_n$ that makes the bound break.

Dont use approximation, you can use upper Riemann sum which will make it $>$ sign.

This integral is not correct: $\int^n_1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},dx=2(\sqrt{n}-1)$

Thank you @Mittens the given example actually not sufficient, I will correct my answer

Your edit goes not solve the problem either since all you have is that $\frac{1}{|x_n|_2}Tx_n$ is bounded. I will not downvote but your answer is not correct.

In all metric space if $x_n$ tends to $a$ and $T(x_n)$ does not tend to $T(a)$ then $T$ is not continuous. The easiest example for this problem is $x_n$ tending to $0$
